# Backbone routes and filtering - a better way

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating an app which receive a collection of data and display it on the page

Since I would like to filter it by location, dates, prices, and rating I had to create the next routes:

```
":location": "func1"
":location/dates/:dates": "func2"
":location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices": "func3"
":location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices/ratings/:ratings": "func4"
":location/dates/:dates/ratings/:ratings": "func5"
":location/prices/:prices": "func6"
":location/prices/:prices/ratings/:ratings": "func7"
":location/ratings/:ratings": "func8"
```

You can see there are duplicates here and I would to avoid it and be able to catch all the filters in the url

How can it be achieved in a better way so I won't need to duplicate routes according to all the possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably reduce it to just one route using optional parameters:

```
":location(/dates/:dates)(/prices/:prices)(/ratings/:ratings)": "func1"
```

Comment: I'm using Ruby on my backend, do I need to set this on the routes.rb too ?

Comment: I haven't used Ruby so I can't help you with that, but it depends of your architecture. If you just want to filter the collection on your client side, you don't need to call your Ruby backend, just when you first load the data of the collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want the :location to be optional too, how do I achieve it?

Comment: Wrapping it with parenthesis but then probably you will be better with `"*splat": "func1"`.